# Catalog price rule apply on products in different categories

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules

I would need some help with Catalog Price Rules.

we're running Magento 2.4.0

There are following categories under root-category:

... Men
..... Underwear
...... Socks

We've product with SKU "1234" in both categories, Underwear and Socks.

There are 2 different catalog price rules:

1. 12% on original for category "Underwear"
2. 2 EUR fixed amount for category "Socks"

For some reason both rules are applied on the SKU in both categories.

Is there any way that SKU "1234" get's 12% in the one category and 2 EUR in the other category? So that the defined reduction is just valid for the category the SKU is assigned to?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

**1. One SKU, different prices**
The *'For some reason both rules are applied on the SKU in both categories.'* is a perfectly normal behavior. **Magento applies all active rules to all matching products, regardless of the page that you are currently navigating.** This is just simply how the catalog rules mechanism is implemented.

My opinion is that you can't simply do what you are asking for, it is simply not how things work :) **A product has to have a final price after all rules have been applied.**

Some scenarios to make it more clear - let's say have successfully achieved the different promotions on different pages for the same SKU - now:

1. you add the product to cart from both categories one after the other - what is the price in cart for the 2 pieces of the same product?
2. you add the product to wishlist, is it fair to display the product price from just one of the categories?
3. what happens if you add the product to wishlist from both categories, which price will be displayed?
4. you are searching for the product in your quick search box and you get on the search results page. Which price is displayed there?
5. which price gets displayed on the product details page also?
6. which price is displayed in related products & co sliders, widgets, etc?

---

**2. Two SKUs, different prices**
And after all of this you are not convinced that this is a bad idea and can't be done by the 'orthodox' ways and you still need to pursue your initial goal, here is a simple workaround that you can apply and *'make things happen'*:

1. you clone your original product (with all its properties, images **BUT different SKU**)
2. you unassign your original product from one of the categories
3. you assign the clone product to the category you just removed the original product from
4. re-apply the catalog rules
5. voila - you now have 'almost the same product' with 2 prices.

The decision belongs to you, but keep in mind that this is confusing for the customers and you will have to handle 2 different SKUs now (which might pose a problem if you have ERP/ PIM/ etc integrations based on SKUs).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for clarification.

Comment: You are most welcome!